# Smarty php double array with index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, smarty

I have the following tpl codes:

```
{foreach from=$data.reviews item=item}
    {$item.user_name},{$item.datestamp}
{/foreach}
```

I'm creating a php file to simulate some data while designing this page. How should I code the array portion? Currently, I have the following:

```
$data = array('reviews' => array('user_name' => 'John',
                                 'datestamp' => '24 April 2012',
                                )
             );
```

However, very strangely the data displayed are JJ and 22. How can I display at least 2 info in the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you're missing a level. What you need is something like:

```
$Smarty->assign( 'data', array(
    'reviews' => array(
        array(
            'user_name' => 'testing',
            'datestamp' => 4534534
        ),
        array(
            'user_name' => 'testing2',
            'datestamp' => 45345343
        ),
    )
) );
```